# how do i use 4 digit numbers

Tags: php, number-formatting

I need to count from:

```
0-9999
```

In PHP, how can i make the format:

```
0000-9999
```

So that the output is:

```
0000,0001,0002,....
```

thanks!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$num = 9;
$paddedNum = sprintf("%04d", $num);
echo $paddedNum; // prints 0009
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$number = 9;
echo str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // output: 0009
```